# What is the meaning of "make up someone's mind"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I don't understand about meaning of word of the phrase: "make up someone's mind".

For example: he makes up his mind about something.

Thanks you for helping.

Comment: There are 4 words there. Do you mean the *phrase*?

Comment: Yes, I want to know meaning of whole phrase: make up someone's mind.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what you've found so far, and why it didn't help. [Here are some dictionaries you can try](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available/2574#2574).

Comment: "He made up his mind" ... so not just someone's mind, but his own mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"to make up *someone's* mind" has two main senses:

1) to decide something about which they are or were unsure about.
2) to make a way of thinking firm and unlikely to change.

> I couldn't make up my mind whether I wanted tacos or burritos.

The writer has a choice to make but is having trouble making the choice.

> She hadn't made up her mind whether to accept his marriage proposal or
>   not, until she thought she had lost him.

Another example of a choice, this time with the reason for the decision included.

> It's useless to try to reason with him once he has made up his mind.

This is the second sense of the word, where a person's way of thinking becomes rigid and not easily changeable.

> She had made up her mind that her boyfriend was cheating on her.
>   Nothing he said could convince her that he was innocent.

Another example where the phrase means that a person won't change their thinking.

Comment: Thank you for good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It means "to decide":

> If you make up your mind or make your mind up, you decide which of a number of possible things you will have or do.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-make-up-your-mind

Comment: I just *knew* this would get a downvote from the "only the Right Sort of Questions are welcome in our club" crowd...